# Is SEAL 3.0 broken?

Tags: stream-cipher

I'll like to know if SEAL 3.0 (cf http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/seal.pdf) is broken. I stumbled on Bernstein's website that claimed that SEAL 3.0 has been broken. (cf http://cr.yp.to/streamciphers/attacks.html)

However, I'm unable to find any papers or proofs that it has indeed been broken. I was hoping to find more information here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a known distinguisher on SEAL presented [here](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45473-X_11) that works with about $2^{43}$ bytes of known plaintext.

As breaks go, this is on the academic side of things; it requires almost as much known plaintext as you can possibly encrypt with a single key, and all it does is distinguish; it tells you nothing about what the key might be (and very little about other ciphertext that might be encrypted with the same key).

On the other hand, by the standards of the cryptographical community, it is a break.

Lastly, it is one of the few examples of using differential cryptanalysis against a stream cipher.